# Problem when try to inject a service into another service using nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm facing a problem.
I have this example repository: https://github.com/pillowslept/nest-example

I want to inject `RaceService` into `HeroService` because I want to use some methods such as `getById`.

I follow the documentation described here: https://docs.nestjs.com/modules

The problems happen when I do next:

At `RaceModule` I added `RaceService` as export:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([RaceEntity])],
  controllers: [RaceController],
  providers: [RaceService],
  exports: [RaceService],
})
```

At `HeroModule` I imported `RaceModule`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [RaceModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([HeroEntity])],
  controllers: [HeroController],
  providers: [HeroService],
})
```

At `HeroService` I added inject for `RaceService`:

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(HeroEntity)
    private heroRepository: Repository<HeroEntity>,
    private readonly raceService: RaceService,
  ) {
  }
```

The error appears at the console:

```
Error: Nest cannot create the module instance. Often, this is because of a circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it
```

I try different ways to import the service, including creating a new CommonsModule, also putting a forwardRef into the raceService definition but another error appears:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HeroService (HeroEntityRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the HeroModule context.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I made a pull request on your GitHub repo, hopefully you find it helpful.

Comment: @Juan Welcome to SO! As your problem seems to be solved, consider adding it as an answer to your own question. Others might profit from your solution and can also see that your problem is already solved. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help I realize that my problem appears because I created a file `index.ts` at the modules folder (with the idea of export the module names at once), like this:

```
export { RaceModule } from './race.module';
... others
```

So, then when I try to import the `RaceModule` at `HeroModule`, like this:

```
import { RaceModule } from 'modules';
```

My problem appears.

I don't know why but referencing the module import directly from the `index.ts` file rather than:

```
import { RaceModule } from 'modules/race.module';
```

Was the problem of my code.

So, following some recommendations, I created some folders and move some files and my project start working as should be.

Thanks for help and hope someone find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import module of race module in hero module